# The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout

Tags: python, flask, azure-web-app-service

[image: Error screen shot]

D:\home\python364x64\python.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout .

I have access to web.config file and my app is hosted in azure . what needs to be changed in order to avoid above error.

Comment: Hi attached error screen shot. please look into it.

Comment: WFastCGI is no longer maintained, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ You should use HttpPlatformHandler to host your web apps on Azure App Service (Windows) if you insist. Migrating to Linux is better if you can.

Answer (score 0):

There are mechanism that lets you modify `applicationhost.config` in arbitrary ways. Check [this document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Site-Extensions#private-extensions) on using a 'Top level private extension' might be helpful.